# Rival and competitor + ter a finish product in the market

Tags: word-choice, expressions

To be able to compete with the other **rivals / competitors**, first we need to **enter a finish product in the market.** 
In the above sentence, I need to know:

> 1. which one of the bold words "competitor" and "rival" can be used here? (the reference is a company.)
> 2. Is there such expression "enter a finish product in the market" in English language? [This is a self-made / translated expression from my mother language.]

Comment: Personally, I probably say "to compete with existing market leaders". As for "enter a finish product in the market", I think you could say "launch a/the/our finished product" or "market a/the/our finished product".

Comment: Thanks dear @Dammkerng for these helpful comments of you. :)

Comment: Anyway I’m afraid I don’t think the syntagm finished product suits correctly in the context of bringing or releasing of a product on the market. Can we do it with an unfinished product? I’d use bringing or releasing of a competitive product, but there would be too many “compete”.

Answer (score 2):

1. While both words are correct, they will communicate slightly different meaning to the reader.  "Rival" is used more in the context of sports competition -- "Arsenal is the rival of Manchester United." "Competitor" is more frequently used in the context business competition.  In the context you present, I would use the word "rivals" if (1) there are only a few competitors AND (2) the competition is particularly fierce.
2. The commonly used phrase in the U.S. is "to bring a finished product to market."

Comment: I would disagree with the first part. A "rival" is a competitor you have a more invested interest in. In other words - all sports teams are competitors, but some sports teams have rivalries with other teams - usually because they are more evenly matched, or had a particularly bad loss. The same would be true with businesses. All businesses in a field compete for customers, but some companies are much closer in scale and thus have more of an interest in beating each other - like Coke vs Pepsi.

Comment: I agree with your assessment and I think that your differentiation is more accurate than mine.

Comment: @Alexander Does it mean that you are more interested because the a "rival" is a team / company / etc. that you have more interest for beating them due to a hostility or because of a very close, old competition? (Like Football derbies)

Comment: @A-friend Sorry for the late response: Both would be acceptable uses of 'rival'.

Answer (score 1):

Both rival and competitor can be used in this context.

For the second it should be finished but I would say: we need to market a complete (finished) product.

Comment: *Market* typically would be taken to mean *advertise* or *promote* in US English, though your usage is correct. *Marketing* is often rather expensive and/or begins before the actual product is released. See [the prototypical case in the video games industry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_of_Duke_Nukem_Forever). In order to truly compete, one must actually have a product available for sale.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName, you are right I agree. (i.e. competitive product instead of finished).

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically and semantically correct choices. Here, I would use *rivals* over *competitors* because *compete with ... competitors* sounds  awkwardly redundant. You might also consider competing *with other companies*, *with other key players*, or *in the industry*.

[As noted previously](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23908/rival-and-competitor-ter-a-finish-product-in-the-market#comment45122_23931), a rivalry is more personal or intimate and usually more aggressive or hotly contested than a competition.

It's rather strange sounding to say *enter a finished product in the market*. I suggest using one of the following instead:

- bring a finished product to market
- release a finished product [*into the market* is understood]

The first choice might sound a little bit old fashioned to some, though there's nothing wrong with its grammar, semantics, or idiomatic usage. It's just unlikely to hear this in an extremely modern, fast moving industry like tech, but I would not bat an eye at encountering it regularly in, say, a meat processing plant.

In the second choice, you might replace *release* with *launch* - typically used for products which will have significant marketing fanfare, add-on items or post-purchase support, and for brands, services or product lines (i.e. more than just a single consumer good) - or *publish* - typically used for things like literary works, research, software, etc.